# Commons Net FTPClient retrieved file encoding issue

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm retrieving a file from a FTP Server. The file is encoded as UTF-8

```
ftpClient.connect(props.getFtpHost(), props.getFtpPort());
ftpClient.login(props.getUsername(), props.getPassword());
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(fileNameBuilder
                    .toString());
```

And then somewhere else I'm reading the input stream

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

But the file is not getting read as UTF-8 Encoded!

I tried `ftpClient.setAutodetectUTF8(true);` but still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
For example a row in the original file is
...00248090041KENAN SARÐIN             00000000015.993FAC...

After downloading it through FTPClient, I parse it and load in a java object, one of the fields of the java object is name, which for this row is read as "KENAN SAR�IN"

I tried dumping to disk directly:

```
File file = new File("D:/testencoding/downloaded-file.txt");
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
ftpClient.retrieveFile(fileName, fop);
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

I compared the MD5 Checksums of the two files(FTP Server one and the and the one dumped to disk), and they're the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate out the problems first: dump the file to disk, and compare it with the original. If it's the same as the original, the problem has nothing to do with UTF-8. The FTP code *looks* okay though, and if you're saying you want the raw binary data, I'd expect it not to mess with anything.

If the file *is* the same after transfer as before, then the problem has nothing to do with FTP. You say "the file is not getting read as UTF-8 Encoded" but it's not clear what you mean. How certain are you that it's UTF-8 text to start with? If you could edit your question with the binary data, how it's being read as text, and how you'd *expect* it to be read as text, that would really help.

Comment: @braincell: You haven't really followed by suggestion though... separate the FTP side from the text encoding side. Save the file directly to disk using `FileOutputStream` (no text at all) and compare it to the original, e.g. with an MD5 hash.

Comment: Jon I tried directly saving to disk, please see my edit. I didn't check with MD5 hash though, but the files look identical to me. Thank you

Comment: @braincell: It all depends on how you looked at them. If you're using *anything* which might infer the encoding, then it's basically a useless test. You've got to look at the individual bytes.

Comment: OK Jon, MD5 Checksum tells they're equal/same files. What now?

Comment: @braincell: Okay, that shows that it's got nothing to do with FTP - it's just a matter of the file really *not* being UTF-8 encoded. If you can edit your post with an example of the *bytes* involved for a troublesome character (use a hex editor to find them) we can validate that.

Comment: Thanks Jon, you were so helpful. I figured it out the file was not encoded using UTF-8. I tried reading it using ISO-8859-9 and it reads it successfully, I guessed it since the characters are turkish.

Comment: @braincell: Glad it worked out - although it would be good to verify this with whatever created the file. If you can make sure that future files *are* encoded with UTF-8, that will guarantee you can cover the whole of Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the file content as bytes and not as characters using InputStream and OutputStream instead of InputStreamReader. This way you are sure that the file is not changed during transfer.